# Is it possible to access a GUI over SSH terminal?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ssh, raspberry-pi4

I am writing a python script on a windows pc which I intend to be used on a Raspberry Pi 4B with an MPU6050 sensor attached to it, the core feature of this script is to have a GUI be created using `tkinter`.

While I can easily connect the RasPi to one of my (2) monitors I only have 1 keyboard and mouse, the crux of my problem is I have a sensor attached to the RasPi which the script is interacting with and I need to see if the GUI is being updated properly and make adjustments more easily without having to constantly swap out cables and connections every time I want to test and fix my code. I am using Git to transfer the files between the devices.

I found a suggestion of SSHing into the RasPi by typing `ssh -Y ras@ip` but only get an error in response `_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`, I'm not sure if I'm running the file the wrong way or there is something else I may need to install to have it work as intended.

Comment: [This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99686/raspberry-pi-error-python-gui-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-var) should answer your question.

Comment: Unrelated: Rather than use `git` to move files, you could just *"share"* your files from Windows and use Samba on the Raspberry Pi to mount the share and access the files directly. Or the Raspberry Pi could share the files with the Windows PC using Samba. Or you could use **SyncThing**. Also, you could maybe consider letting the Raspberry Pi offer a web interface that any client could access via a browser rather than needing an X11 server package. Or you could try RDP or VNC. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: @steTATO, thanks for the link, the answer given of changing the Display helped a lot as it gave me a different perspective as to what I was trying to do.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I chose to use `git` purely primarily for its version control and safe storage, I see this as more of a personal project and if I find it works I wouldn't mind letting others use the code at a later date (not that I'm doing anything ground breaking). Also I had tried using a web interface at the beginning of it but wasnt able to figure out how to get that to work so I tried simplifying it to just a python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally pieced together the solution.

First of I was supposed to be using PuTTY which I believe allows for X11 forwarding as opposed to using powershell as I had been doing already, I also found I needed to install a software called Xming which is used to run the X server on my pc(I am not sure what exactly it does but it works).

On running Xming and turning on X11 forwarding in PuTTY and connecting to the remote RasPi I was able to run the test script I had and the GUI appeared on my pc's monitor which I could interact with like any other windows.

Comment: Using MobaXterm is more convenient as it has the built-in X-Server (what Xming is).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).